# Changing heatmap ticks from numbers to months in R

Tags: r, heatmap, axis-labels

I have heatmap with month number on the y-axis. I want to change the numbers to month name (e.g., "Jan.","Feb.","Mar.","Apr.").
Here is the heatmap

[image]

and this is my code:

```
heatmap(data, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, margins=c(3,3),
                   col = magma(50), scale="none", xlab = "Hours",
                   ylab = "Month")
```

Comment: @MrFlick it worked :) Your way was interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values printed on the axes are determined by the row and column names of the object you pass in. There is a built in vector of month abbreviations that you can use. Try

```
rownames(data) <- month.abb
```

Or you could set the values to whatever you like.